# Applied / environmental question: direction of exhaust fumes

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics

I'm not sure the Physics StackExchange is the perfect place for this environmental/applied physics question, but as I found no forum more fitting I ask my question here. Otherwise please move my question.

**Main Question**

**In which direction will the fumes move when leaving the exhaust of a car?** No aerial movement or wind is assumed. On cold winter days it can be seen that the initial direction is horizontal or downwards, forming small fume clouds behind the car. Where to will the fumes move from there on?

The fumes assumingly have a higher temperature than the surrounding air, indicating they will rise. Nevertheless cooling effects and density may eliminate or surpass this effect.

**Sub-question**

My office is in 3rd floor next to a main traffic road. Will parts of the fumes enter the room when I open the window? (This is where my initial inspiration to this question comes from)

Comment: I don't think the situation is specified precisely enough to be answered. Exhaust fume movement is likely to be dominated by air currents since gas diffusion is too slow to be relevant and temperature differences will rapidly dissipate as the fumes mix with air.

Comment: Ok. How would you narrow the question? I know it's quite difficult to break down.

Comment: If you're asking about exhaust fumes reaching a third floor window that's likely to be due to air currents, and obviously this depends on the environmental conditions where you work.